# Create a new user at startup in Fedora Linux

Tags: linux, fedora, boot, user-accounts, user

I have this virtual machine with Fedora KDE. I want to distribute it but without any default user, except the root of course or another skeleton one. In the first run the person that runs it should have the ability to create a user with username that chooses. I have also a set of scripts to run in this first login.
Is there any way to create a user in start up without the need to login root? Is there any application doing that in welcome screen?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is a package in Fedora distribution called `firstboot`

```
$ rpm -qi firstboot
Name        : firstboot
Version     : 17.3
Release     : 1.fc17
URL         : http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/FirstBoot
Summary     : Initial system configuration utility
Description :
The firstboot utility runs after installation.  It guides the user through
a series of steps that allows for easier configuration of the machine.
```

Although it is not documented, it is written in python and it has a modular structure.

So, I think you could customize it for your needs.